# How many new powers do you unlock when you get 6 dots in a Discipline?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-dark-ages

I finally have a character in a Vampire the Dark Ages game who got to 7th Generation via Diablerie and saw that his new Trait Max is 6. As far as I am aware that means that in addition to his Attributes now having a maximum rating of 6 his Clan Disciplines can now go to 6 as well.

So I went to read up on [Vicissitude 6](http://whitewolf.wikia.com/wiki/Vicissitude) since he already has it at 5 and saw the following 9 powers listed:

- Body Arsenal: Transform the bones in your body into weapons
- Blood of Acid: Permanently make your vitae highly corrosive
- Chiropteran Marauder: Transform into a huge, flying bat
- Ecstatic Agony: Change the pain of wounds into pleasure
- Entrail Saraband: Turn your bowels into writhing tendrils
- Graft Life to Life: Attach the limbs of one person to another without it becoming useless
- Living Testudo: Use a victim as a living weapon and shield
- Plasmic Form: As Bloodform, except you can move and hold any shape as a pool
- Skin Trap: Peel off a layer of skin to use as a net

Would spending 25XP to get Rank 6 give him all of those powers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you choose one of those powers only.

If your character were to lower his Generation again, you would have an option of taking any of the powers listed for Vicissitude 7, or one of the ones you didn't previously take from Vicissitude 6 if you prefer.

Comment: Could he spend an additional 25XP for a second power without going to Rank 7?

Comment: I don't see why not, from now on it would be treated as any other discipline - pay XP to get a power.

Comment: You can purchase any number of techniques of a given rank. The Discipline rank is highest Discipline technique rank you possess.

Answer (score 8):

As @DaemonH said, you choose only one power when you get any Discipline on level 6+. If that Discipline is Celerity, Fortitude or Potence, you would also have to choose if you get a power from "Advanced Celerity" (Potence/Fortitude) section, or a normal progression, such as an additional Celerity action in combat. However, you may pay additional XP and learn another power of level 6, learn as many as you want.

Though, consult your Storyteller if you are allowed to do this. The powers you listed come from different editions, so do ask your Storyteller if you plan to aquire them.

If that character lowers his Generation again, he would be able to learn even more advanced powers of level 7th, again choosing only one power from the list and being able to buy another power by paying more XP.

I strongly suggest you to reread the part about High-Level Disciplines on page 188 of DAV20 and page 127 of V20 Core, you seem to have missed something from there.

Also note that some Advanced Disciplines may break your game. Perhaps, if that happens, you should agree with your Storyteller to rechoose a power.